# Why does `echo | xargs > >(cat)` hang on my Mac?

Tags: bash, macos, zsh, xargs

This is reproducible in `zsh` and `bash`.

Confusing me further, `echo | ( xargs; : ) > >(cat)` does not hang. This is also reproducible in `zsh` and `bash`.

If I use GNU's `xargs` as provided by `brew install findutils` it doesn't hang: `echo | gxargs > >(cat)`.

Indeed I haven't found any other program besides my system's `xargs` that behaves this way. I figured there might be something `xargs` is doing with the file descriptors so I tried replacing `xargs` with `bash -c 'kill -9 $$'` or `bash -c 'exec 0<&- 1<&-'` or many other shots in the dark.

I also sought help on `##mac`, `#macosx`, `##linux`, and `#bash` on Freenode but no one there seemed to know what was going on.

---

```
> sw_vers | head -n 2
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.2

> zsh --version
zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)

> bash --version | head -n 1
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)

> strings $(which xargs) | grep 'xargs.c'
$FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/xargs/xargs.c,v 1.57 2005/02/27 02:01:31 gad Exp $

> gxargs --version | head -n 1
xargs (GNU findutils) 4.7.0
```

Comment: Interesting. As a further twist (in `zsh`, but *not* `bash`), if you close standard input by typing Control-D, then kill `cat` from another window, the entire *shell* exits. Killing `cat` before you close its standard input just causes a normal completion of the pipeline.

Comment: I see activity still on this question despite it being closed, so for anyone seeking an answer to this, [I posted on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1523103/1137062) and figured it out there.